# How to call on Web Service API and route data into Azure SQL Database?

Tags: web-services, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Having configured an Azure SQL Database, I would like to feed some tables with data from an HTTP REST GET call.
I have tried Microsoft Flow (whose HTTP Request action is utterly botched) and I am now exploring Azure Data Factory, to no avail.
The only way I can currently think of is provisioning an Azure VM and install Postman with Newman. But then, I would still need to create a Web Service interface to the Azure SQL Database.

Does Microsoft offer no HTTP call service to hook up to an Azure SQL Database?

Comment: To specify, I know of the WebLinkedService, but that service does not seem to support authentication via Raw, OAuth, or any token based authentication. I would be able to set up a custom authentication method, but I require access to HTTP headers for that. How to add HTTP headers? I guess you need them anyway for parameters such as Content-Type.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same situation a couple of weeks ago and I ended up building the API call management using Azure Functions. No problem to use the Azure SDK's to upload the result to e.g BLOB store or Data Lake. And you can add whatever assembly you need to perform the HTTP post operation.

From their you can easily pull it with Data Factory to a Azure SQL db.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you write yourself an Azure Data Factory custom activity to achieve this. I've done this for a recent project.

Add a C# class library to your ADF solution and create a class that inherits from IDotNetActivity. Then in the IDictionary method make the HTTP web request to get the data. Land the downloaded file in blob storage first, then have a downstream activity to load the data into SQL DB.

```
public class GetLogEntries : IDotNetActivity
{     
    public IDictionary<string, string> Execute(
        IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices,
        IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets,
        Activity activity,
        IActivityLogger logger)
    {
```

etc...

```
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

You can use the ADF linked services to authenticate against the storage account and define where container and file name you want as the output etc.

This is an example I used for data lake. But there is an almost identical class for blob storage.

```
        Dataset outputDataset = datasets.Single(dataset => dataset.Name == activity.Outputs.Single().Name);

        AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService outputLinkedService;

        outputLinkedService = linkedServices.First(
            linkedService =>
            linkedService.Name ==
            outputDataset.Properties.LinkedServiceName).Properties.TypeProperties
            as AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService;
```

Don't bother with an input for the activity.

You will need an Azure Batch Service as well to handle the compute for the compiled classes. Check out my blog post on doing this.

https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/11/creating-azure-data-factory-custom-activities/

Hope this helps.